# Find variance of $\bar X$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ be random variables with common mean $\mu$, common variance $\sigma^2$, and common correlation coefficient $\rho$, where $\rho>0$. Find $Var(\bar X)$ and determine whether this variance is smaller than, equal to, or larger than the variance of $\bar X$ when the observations are uncorrelated.

Because $\bar X=\frac{X_1+X_2+...+X_n}{n}$ with each $a_i=\frac{1}{n}$, we have $Var(\bar X)=Var(\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{X_i}{n})=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}Var(X_i)+2\sum\sum_{i<j}\frac{1}{n^2}Cov(X_i,X_j)=\frac{1}{n^2}[\sum_{i=1}^nVar(X_i)+2\sum\sum_{i<j}Cov(X_i,X_j)]$

I'm stuck here. I know that $Cov(X_i,X_j)=\rho_{ij}\sigma_i\sigma_j=\rho\sigma^2$, because that's given in the problem statement, but I'm not sure how to deal with the double sum. Why do we take the double sum here?

Comment: For a small example, $\text{Var}(X_1+X_2+X_3) = \text{Var}(X_1) + \text{Var}(X_2) + \text{Var}(X_3) + 2 \text{Cov}(X_1, X_2) + 2 \text{Cov}(X_1, X_3) + 2 \text{Cov}(X_2, X_3)$.

Answer (score 1):

The "double sum" is simply because you have two indices. One sometimes also writes $\sum_{i<j}$ instead of $\sum\sum_{i<j}$. Now since you are summing a constant:
$$
\sum\sum_{i<j}\rho\sigma^2\tag{1}
$$
all you need is to count the number of pairs $(i,j)$ with $i<j$, and the result of (1) is that number times $\rho\sigma^2$.

It is revealing to try a simple example when $n=3$ as angryavian's [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4306000/find-variance-of-bar-x/4306002#comment8969885_4306000) pointed out.

Comment: So $\sum\sum_{i<j}\tag{1}={n \choose 2}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$? The binomial coefficient works here because we want the number of ways in which $i$ and $j$ can be chosen without replacement from $n$ different objects whereby the order of selection is irrelevant since we exclude the pairs $(i,j)$ with $i>j$?

Comment: And $Var(\bar X)=\frac{\sigma^2(1-\rho)}{n}+\rho\sigma^2$?

Comment: @Karam: Yes, your (1) is correct. And your final calculation is also correct. See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sum_of_correlated_variables